# Check if URL contains certain strings

Tags: php, parsing, if-statement

How can I check if the url (`$u`) has `embed-` and `.html` in it?

I've this:

```php
function embed($u){
$servidores = array('http://powvideo.net/', 'http://gamovideo.com/', 'http://vidspot.net/');
$embedurl = array('http://powvideo.net/embed-', 'http://gamovideo.com/embed-', 'http://vidspot.net/embed-');
    $a = str_replace($servidores, $embedurl, $u);
return $a.'.html';
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know if `str_replace` did make a replacement or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the path from the url, and check if it begins with `'/embed'`:

```
function embed($u){
  $path = parse_url($u, PHP_URL_PATH);
  if(strpos($path, '/embed-') === 0) {
      return $u;
  }
  $servidores = array('http://powvideo.net/', 'http://gamovideo.com/', 'http://vidspot.net/');
  $embedurl = array('http://powvideo.net/embed-', 'http://gamovideo.com/embed-', 'http://vidspot.net/embed-');
  $a = str_replace($servidores, $embedurl, $u);
  return $a.'.html';
}

echo embed('http://powvideo.net/embed-n790e6gzhmmp-960x450.html') . "\n";

echo embed('http://powvideo.net/n790e6gzhmmp-960x450') . "\n";
```

Comment: This return the URL without `/embed-` and `.html`

Comment: I put the code into the function and added usage examples.